# Does Zxing RIM build work for Bold, Storm and Tour?

Tags: blackberry, barcode, zxing

I need to know if the Zxing RIM build works on the latest Blackberries to scan 1d bar codes.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm the dev BTW.) Yes and no. Yes in the sense that it should build and run; we don't support it and I didn't even write that particular client, but AFAIK it does work. It does link to support for all formats including 1D.

However the client was written for older BB OSes, which didn't have real camera API support. It does what readers used to have to do on BBs: ask the camera app to start, and save a photo to storage, and then hope the user comes back to the reader.

It's not a nice experience, and now with better APIs available on later devices and OSes like the ones you mention, far from the best experience. So it doesn't work well in that sense.